# How to install phonenumbers for Django

Tags: django, ubuntu

there!

I am trying to run an imported app on my Ubuntu. But the error message displayed on the screen says `No module named phonenumbers`

So I tried to install it, by:

```
sudo easy_install phonenumbers
```

But again, it throws error, and says `ImportError: No module named shortdata`

Then I tried to run

```
sudo easy_install shortdata
```

This time it gives me:

```
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('shortdata')
```

I cannot figure out how to install 'shortdata'.

What can I do, to make 'phonenumbers' installed?

Answer (score 0):

The issue happening because the module 'shortdata' is get missing while installation. You can correct the issue by installing from source and manually copy the module 'shortdata'.

```
1)Download source from https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers 
2)Install phonenumbers using setup.py (python setup.py install)
3)Manually copy folder 'shortdata' from python-phonenumbers-dev/python/phonenumbers in source to your installed location(python2.7/site-packages/phonenumbers-5.7b1-py2.7.egg/phonenumbers)
```